# My schema doesn't appear on MySQL WorkBench schemas panel

Tags: mysql

I always copy a folder of MySQL db data into `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server [x.x]\Data` folder. And this db schema would appear after I restart the MySQL service.

However, this time I installed a new MySQL on a computer and followed the old way throwing MySchema folder into `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server [x.x]\Data` and restarted the service. It didn't work.

I checked my.ini `datadir = C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server [x.x]\Data`.

What did I miss?

[image]
[image]

Edit:

I find a clue, my newly installed MySQL the table extension name is ibd, but my data table is frm, MYD and MYI.

Comment: your server configuration might have changed

Comment: @SandrinJoy, It's just newly installed.

Comment: Use data import/export or schema transfer wizard tools that are available on workbench itself. Doing things manually is error-prone